# Limit of $x/|x|$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit of

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{x}{|x|}$$

My guess is that it is $1$ if approached from $0+$ and $-1$ if approached from $0-$

Thanks

Comment: So basically the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Good guess! So, how can you write rigorously what you 'know' intuitevely? Using the definition of the limit what does this mean here? Make a try.

Comment: Well I am not sure how to show it mathematically  rigorously, because L'Hospital's rule just turns the fraction upside down so you can't really guess from that. But graphically it makes sense. Would appreciate a hint here. But I have a more urgent problem related to this. If the limits can be evaluated in this way what is then: $\int \frac{x}{|x|}\delta(x)dx$

Comment: @onephys You don't need L'Hospital, I think. Divide the cases.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule does not make it inconclusive. You cannot use the Rule unless you first apply the definition of the absolute value. You then must observe the right hand limit and the left hand limit separately to find 1 and -1 which is confirmed by the graph. Hence as indicated earlier, THE limit does not exist.

Comment: Thanks MXYMXY. Well it is kind of trivial then, isn't it?

Comment: @onephys Here is a nice follow up question for you: Is your function differentiable at $x=0$ ?

Comment: What exactly does it mean to say that the limit (as $x\rightarrow 0$ of $\frac{x}{|x|}$) exists?

Comment: @ imranfat:my guess is not, but then the derivative prefers a direction so maybe it could be 1. I guess this is a problem, which one could argue about for hours. One would probably need to be mathematically meticulous. I am just a physics student.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we should discuss two cases for this question (according to definition of modulus function)

if $x>0$ the function is $$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{x}{x}, x>0$$
**LHL**

$$\implies\lim_{x\to 0+}1=1$$

if $x<0$ the function is $$\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{x}{-x}, x<0$$

**RHL**

$$\lim_{x\to 0-}-1=-1$$

as you can see left hand limit is not equal to right hand limit. So limit doesn't exist!!

**Note:**

the + and - signs in limits

Answer (score 1):

As $\ x \rightarrow 0 $ it can approach it from negative side and positive side.
For
Left Hand Limit: $\ x \rightarrow 0- $
i.e, $x<0$
Hence $|x|$ = $-x$
So $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-} \ x/|x|$ = $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-} \ x/(-x)$ = $-1$
Similarly for
 Right Hand Limit: $\ x \rightarrow 0+$
Now $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} \ x/|x|$ = $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-} \ x/(x)$ = $+1$
Since
RHL $\neq$ LHL
Therefore Limit doesn't exist.